# Notice if user changes to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Has someone an idea how I can check if the user works currently in the iframe?
E. g. the user clicks into the iframe. I know that I can't get any information about the target but the iframe element it self is embedded into my website, so the question is: is there any way to detect if the user "activates" or "focuses" the iframe element?
The "onactivate" and "onfocus" actions doesn't work in Chrome...

Edit: I want the parent window to detect if the user changes to the iframe. The frame is on my domain.

Comment: Maybe an `onclick` handler for the `<body>`?

Comment: Doesn't work either. The click is only detected if it isn't in the iframe.

Comment: You mean you want the parent document to detect when you start working in the child? I thought the iframe document wanted to detect when you entered it.

Comment: Is the iframe your site as well? On the same domain etc?

Comment: Yeah it is. You thought about communication between both sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the inner `iframe` are under your control, then you can try:

1. Capture `onclick` and `onfocus` events on the `<body>` of the internal `iframe`
2. [Post a message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to `window.parent`.
3. On the parent, listen to that message and take appropriate action.

However, note that [messaging is only supported IE8+](http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging).